# Как поставить фокус на контрол при открытии приложения

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, focus

Как сделать, чтобы при открытии приложения, не пользователь нажимал на текстбокс, а программа сама на него нажимала и юзер должен будет ввести пароль? Пример: Окно с вводом логина и пароля. Пользователь запускает приложение и при открытии сразу же активируется поле логина и он вводит логин(без пользовательского клика на это же поле).

Comment: это называется "установить фокус"

Answer (score 3):

Нужно задать этому контролу свойство [TabIndex](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex?view=netframework-4.8) равное 0 - тогда он будет самым первым элементом, принимающим фокус. Свойство [TabStop](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tabstop?view=netframework-4.8) при этом должно быть установлено в `true` (по умолчанию так и есть).

Смотрите [How to: Set the tab order on Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-set-the-tab-order-on-windows-forms).

PS: вынужден отметить, что в последние годы многие разработчики слыхом не слыхивали о порядке обхода элементов в окне приложения или на веб-странице. И нажатие на Tab фокусирует их в неопределённом порядке. В итоге пользоваться ими без мышки, одной лишь клавиатурой, становится чертовски неудобно.

Comment: "да кто сейчас пользуется клавиатурой? 21 век! даже мышь уже устарела, вам что пальцев мало?" - шучу разумеется, согласен с каждым словом.

Answer (score 1):

Если я не ошибаюсь в панели свойств есть параметр `focus` его надо поставить на `true`.

Comment: Ошибаетесь. Нет такого свойства.

Comment: а вы на какой версии VS работаете?

Answer (score 1):

Вызови `YourTextBot.Focus()` при отображении твоей формы

Comment: В общем, да. Но нужно знать, когда именно можно вызвать этот метод. Смотрим эту [тему](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6597196/5045688). Нужно использовать событие `Shown`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov А я так и написал